# django-tables2 - show all per page

Tags: django, django-tables2

Good afternoon,

im using Django-tables2, I know in the query string I can set per_page and have used the below template tag to create some urls

```
{% querystring "per_page"=20 %}
```

however is it possible to show all items per page via a url? ive tried using -1 and 0 but it does not work, the only thing I can think to is put a ridiculous number like a billon which works, but I dont think thats a clean implementation?

Thanks